# Passing multiple lists to subprocess

Tags: python, list, subprocess

I have the following python code:

```
var_b='en'
var_c='cs'
var_d='false'
var_e=str(Path.home())

IDS='TEST_123'

L1 = [1, 2 , 3, 4]
L2 = ['env', L1, f'a={var_b}']
CMD = ['COMMAND']
L3 = [IDS]
L4 = [f'--b {var_b}', f'--c {var_c}']
L5 = [f'--d {var_d}', f'--e {var_e}.xml', L4]
```

I would like to execute a terminal command using subprocess to make the end command entry on the terminal looks in the combination `L2 CMD L3 L5` i.e.

```
**L2 CMD L3 L5**
env 1 2 3 4 a=en COMMAND TEST_123 --d false --e /path/to/home.xml --b en --c cs
```

Here is what i have tried:

```
subprocess.run([*L2, *CMD, *L3, *L5])
```

But i'm getting this error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Could someone please suggest how to implement this.

Comment: @Hihikomori Not really. `L2` contains a list itself, `L1`, which consists of numbers.

Comment: you could fix the L1 in L2 by doing L2 = ['env', *L1, f'a={var_b}']... same for L5&L4, so @Hihikomori's suggestion makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this unpacking `*` goes only one level deep. But you want to unpack every level in order to get a flat list. You should do something like this:

```
import itertools
from pathlib import Path

def flatten_to_strings(l):
    """Flatten a list or tuple, turning the remaining components into strings."""
    if not isinstance(l, (list, tuple)):
        return [str(l)]
    flat = (flatten_to_strings(i) for i in l)
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(flat))
```

With this and your code, you can do

```
print(flatten_to_strings([*L2, *CMD, *L3, *L5]))
```

and it prints

```
['env', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'a=en', 'COMMAND', 'TEST_123', '--d false', '--e /home/glglgl.xml', '--b en', '--c cs']
```

---

Alternatively, you could assemble your lists as you need them to be:

```
L1 = [str(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]] # so that they are strings
L2 = ['env', *L1, f'a={var_b}']     # unpack L1 early
CMD = ['COMMAND']
L3 = [IDS]
L4 = [f'--b {var_b}', f'--c {var_c}']
L5 = [f'--d {var_d}', f'--e {var_e}.xml', *L4] # unpack L4 early
```

This way,

```
print([*L2, *CMD, *L3, *L5])
```

gives

```
['env', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'a=en', 'COMMAND', 'TEST_123', '--d false', '--e /home/glglgl.xml', '--b en', '--c cs']
```

as well.

Comment: What is flatten? There is no such built in function.

Comment: Please don't use `sum(list,[])`. Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(list)` instead

Comment: @Hihikomori It was supposed to call itself recursively; I renamed the function, but forgot to change its use.

Answer (score 0):

For the case if L2 contains some L6 as and so on, there must be recursion:

```
var_b='en'
var_c='cs'
var_d='false'
var_e=str("Path.home()")

IDS='TEST_123'

L1 = [1, 2 , 3, 4]
L2 = ['env', L1, f'a={var_b}']
CMD = ['COMMAND']
L3 = [IDS]
L4 = [f'--b {var_b}', f'--c {var_c}']
L5 = [f'--d {var_d}', f'--e {var_e}.xml', L4]

def build_string_recursively(command_list):
    ret = []
    for command in command_list:
        if isinstance(command,list):
            ret+=build_string_recursively(command)
        else:
            ret.append(command)
    return ret

print(build_string_recursively(L2+CMD+L3+L5))
```

This also gives desired:

```
['env', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'a=en', 'COMMAND', 'TEST_123', '--d false', '--e Path.home().xml', '--b en', '--c cs']
```